# docker - php - permissions

Tags: php, bash, docker, docker-compose

I am programming a web server using xampp and when uploading it to production where I use docker I have found this problem:

```
2021/04/28 08:58:19 [crit] 15#15: *4 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/0000000001" failed (13: Permission denied), client: XXX, server: , request: "POST /admin/data/test.php HTTP/1.1", host: "XXX", referrer: "https://XXX/admin/data/othercsv.php"
```

I entered docker using "sh" and changed the permissions with `chmod -R 755 /var/lib/nginx` and it worked perfectly. later I have seen that with `chgrp -R nginx /var/lib/nginx` it also worked.

So I have gone to my `docker-compose.yaml` and added the`command: bash -c "chgrp -R nginx /var/lib/nginx";` getting a 502 error all over the web, I have tried with everything that crossed my mind and google too, even `entrypoint: [ "sh", "-c", "sleep 10 && chgrp -R nginx /var/lib/nginx"]` and `command: [sh, -c, "chmod -R 755 /var/lib/nginx";]`. Also loading external files with the commands and trying to execute them externally. But I have not been lucky.

Code in docker-compose:

```
  nginx_web:
    image: tobi312/php:8.0-fpm-nginx-alpine
    hostname: XXX
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/XXX:/var/www/html:rw
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=XXX
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=XXX
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=XXX
      - ENABLE_NGINX_REMOTEIP=1
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    depends_on:
       - mongodb
       - nginx-proxy
```

(I am using docker proxy)
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you add `chmod -R 755 /var/lib/nginx` to your dockerfile? Or can you change the runtime user of your dockerfile to a different user? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user

Comment: When you add `command: bash -c "chgrp -R nginx /var/lib/nginx";` the command will be appended to the image entrypoint, and will result in execute `nginx -g bash -c "chgrp -R nginx /var/lib/nginx` which is not what you want. 
Also `entrypoint: [ "sh", "-c", "sleep 10 && chgrp -R nginx /var/lib/nginx"]`will override your entrypoint and prevent nginx from running  

Can you share with us the part where you added a the command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution came from the creator of the docker image. His solution was `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx/*`. Directly in docker.

Thank you all!

I will continue looking for ways to include commands on docker-compose

[Link to Issue](https://github.com/Tob1asDocker/php/issues/2)

Answer (score 0):

The docker image you are using supports additional entrypoint scripts, as show here the `entrypoint.sh` for the image, executes all the scripts under `/entrypoint.d`. So you can make use of it.

Create a `chmod-www-dir.sh` and make it executable in your machine `chmod u+x chmod-www-dir.sh` and mount it into the `/entrypoint.d`.

The script will look something like this

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
chgrp -R nginx /var/lib/nginx
```

And the compose-file

```yaml
nginx_web:
    image: tobi312/php:8.0-fpm-nginx-alpine
    hostname: XXX
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/XXX:/var/www/html:rw
      - ./chmod-www-dir.sh:/entrypoint.d
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=XXX
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=XXX
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=XXX
      - ENABLE_NGINX_REMOTEIP=1
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    depends_on:
       - mongodb
       - nginx-proxy
```

when you container will start it will execute the `chmod-www-dir.sh` as part of the `entrypoint.sh` script. and will change the file permissions for the files in already mounted volume

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, it returns an error saying it doesn't understand what a ".sh" is.